# Passing multiple ng-template to child component

Tags: angular

**Parent component:**

```
<child-component>
    <ng-template optionItem>Option item 1</ng-template>  <---- want to send this template to child
    <ng-template optionItem>Option item 2</ng-template>  <---- want to send this template to child
    ... // more ng-template here //
</child-component>
```

**Child component:**

```
 <thirdparty-package>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
 </thirdparty-package>
```

I am trying to pass multiple ng-templates to `Child component` so that the thirdparty-package component can process it as usual with the following structure.

```
 // expected structure
 <thirdparty-package>
     <ng-template optionItem>Option item 1</ng-template>
     <ng-template optionItem>Option item 2</ng-template>
 // more ng-template here //
 </thirdparty-package>
```

but seems like `ng-content` is empty and not able to find those templates.

```
 // but what i get is this 
 <thirdparty-package>
 // missing ng-templates //
 </thirdparty-package>
```

How can I send **multiple sets of `ng-template`** to child component and put inside `<thirdparty-package></thirdparty-package>`?

> I have tried @input and TemplateOutlet with no better results

```
<child-component [myTemplate]="myTemplate"></child-component>
   <ng-container #myTemplate>
      <ng-template optionItem>Item A</ng-template>
      <ng-template optionItem>Item B</ng-template>
   </ng-container>
```

Appreciate your help...

Comment: maybe you are searching for smoething like i answered a couple of weeks ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648691/how-to-resolve-dynamic-components-in-angular-4-or-5/48648755#48648755

Comment: Hi @messerbill I might not need to load component dynamically. I need the ng-templates to be passed down to the child for child to load. But it seems like the ng-templates was lost on the way to the child component.

Comment: Hi @Danaley,  Did you get to solve this as I'm trying the do the same without any success

Comment: Hi @LogixMaster, no I did not proceed to this approach. Instead, my third-party package supports `exportAs` property so i could get its directive. Hence, problem is solve with that. [exportAs](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26)